# Error with Jboss while deploying a jsp/servlet web app "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" Error

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jboss, maven-2

I am working on JSP/Servlets. The web app is to be deployed on Jboss 6.

I am using Java 1.6, Eclipse and Maven2. I do not refer to JSF anywhere in my code.

My project doesnot have JSF involved anywhere, but when I try to deploy my webapp WAR I get an error that says :

> 21:55:44,448 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/UltimateSMS-1 21:55:44,493 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/UltimateSMS-1]] Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

Here is my POM and `web.xml`

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>UltimateSMS</groupId>
    <artifactId>UltimateSMS</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>UltimateSMS</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <configuration>

                <!-- 
                    <jbossHome>/opt/jboss6/server/default/deploy</jbossHome>
                     -->
                     <jbossHome>/home/jamshed/jboss-6.0.0.Final/</jbossHome>
                    <serverName>default</serverName>
                    <fileName>target/UltimateSMS.war</fileName>
                    <path>/UltimateSMS</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>5.14.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-hibernate3</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-j2ee</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <!-- 
             <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
             -->
             <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>

            <version>6.0</version>
            <!-- Added below -->
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <!-- end -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>trove</groupId>
            <artifactId>trove</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-beta-5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SendMessage</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.SendMessage</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>AddContact</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AddContact</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.AddContact</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>AddCoverage</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AddCoverage</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.AddCoverage</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Addgroup</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Addgroup</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.Addgroup</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>AddGroup</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AddGroup</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.AddGroup</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>AddOperator</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AddOperator</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.AddOperator</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>AddStartNumber</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AddStartNumber</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.AddStartNumber</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>AddUser</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AddUser</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.AddUser</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>AdminSimpleReport</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AdminSimpleReport</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.AdminSimpleReport</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>DisplayAddressBook</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DisplayAddressBook</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.DisplayAddressBook</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Download</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Download</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.Download</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>DownloadFile</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DownloadFile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.DownloadFile</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>EditPrefix</display-name>
    <servlet-name>EditPrefix</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.EditPrefix</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Etoptlst</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Etoptlst</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.Etoptlst</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>feedback</display-name>
    <servlet-name>feedback</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.feedback</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>GetCredit</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GetCredit</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.GetCredit</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>GetDate</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GetDate</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.GetDate</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>GetFailDate</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GetFailDate</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.GetFailDate</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Login</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Numeric</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Numeric</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.Numeric</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>OperatorMonth</display-name>
    <servlet-name>OperatorMonth</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.OperatorMonth</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>ProcessUser</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ProcessUser</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.ProcessUser</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>SendMessageFromConact</display-name>
    <servlet-name>SendMessageFromConact</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.SendMessageFromConact</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>SendSmsInFuture</display-name>
    <servlet-name>SendSmsInFuture</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.SendSmsInFuture</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>SMSSender</display-name>
    <servlet-name>SMSSender</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.misc.SMSSender</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SendMessage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SendMessage</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddContact</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AddContact</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddCoverage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AddCoverage</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Addgroup</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Addgroup</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddGroup</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AddGroup</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddOperator</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AddOperator</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddStartNumber</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AddStartNumber</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddUser</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AddUser</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminSimpleReport</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AdminSimpleReport</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DisplayAddressBook</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DisplayAddressBook</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Download</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Download</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DownloadFile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DownloadFile</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EditPrefix</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/EditPrefix</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Etoptlst</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Etoptlst</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>feedback</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/feedback</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GetCredit</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GetCredit</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GetDate</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GetDate</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GetFailDate</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GetFailDate</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Numeric</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Numeric</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OperatorMonth</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/OperatorMonth</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ProcessUser</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ProcessUser</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SendMessageFromConact</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SendMessageFromConact</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SendSmsInFuture</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SendSmsInFuture</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SMSSender</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SMSSender</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>template.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here's the complete Stack trace:

```
21:55:44,448 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/UltimateSMS-1
21:55:44,493 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/UltimateSMS-1]] Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266) [:1.6.0_20]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:278) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:264) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3319) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3828) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:294) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:477) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:95) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.6.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) [:1.6.0_20]
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at $Proxy41.start(Unknown Source)   at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:53) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:41) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:301) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:894) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:641) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:182) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:58) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.deploy(HDScanner.java:240) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.complete(HDScanner.java:192) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(TwoPCActionWrapper.java:57) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:135) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:146) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:90) [:0.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [:1.6.0_20]

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/UltimateSMS-1" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/home/jamshed/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/tmp/vfs/automount32136eeb452eb1b9/UltimateSMS-1.war-9f7ce8e7ceadff1/ deployment failed
```

Why do I get this error from JBoss? Is it a POM dependency causing this error?

Comment: I don't do Maven, but you've got there a `jboss-j2ee` dependency of version `4.0.2` which definitely doesn't look quite right as you're running JBoss 6. Try to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If  i get rid of the jboss-j2ee dependency i start to get errors on compilation (When i do a mvn clean install). what do you reckon i do ??

Answer (score 0):

> URL
>   file:/home/jamshed/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/tmp/vfs/automount32136eeb452eb1b9/UltimateSMS-1.war-9f7ce8e7ceadff1/

I believe this would the path to the working space for building the war file.  Perhaps it is possible to take a look in there and see if you are able to find the WAR itself that it is attempting to deploy?

What I am getting at is, see if you can build or obtain your war file and try to manually deploy it to JBoss.  If it doesn't work then there is something missing on your classpath for JBoss, if it does then there is something missing in Maven or your pom.

Comment: I did have a look,  when i manually deploy the war without building it via maven thru the admin console, it works. But when i build via maven and copy the war to the deploy dir. I get the faces error. Btw i use apache-maven-3.0.3

Comment: Thats great, we narrowed the problem down.  Well then there is something definitely wrong with your pom file, but unfortunately I am rather new to Maven and can't help you with that.  I would refer to BalusC's comment to the question above and see if this fixes your maven deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem. To resolve it I've replace in `pom.xml` :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
         <version>6.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

by :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

According to [maven doc](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) you should set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope `provided` because the web container provides those classes.

`provided` is much like `compile`, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.