# ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener - Deployment of jars to Tomcat configured under Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment, classnotfoundexception

I have a problem very similar to these:

1. [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener when using MyFaces with WASCE/Geronimo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777844/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener-when-us)
2. [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848341/classnotfoundexception-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener-for-jsf-project-u)
3. [Error with Jboss while deploying a jsp/servlet web app "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967905/error-with-jboss-while-deploying-a-jsp-servlet-web-app-com-sun-faces-config-con)

I've managed to find a workaround but still not solved the issue.

When I deploy my application to Tomcat 7.0.34 which is configured in Eclipse Juno Service Release 1 (Build id: 20120920-0800) I get:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
maj 22, 2013 5:10:34 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\ProjName\Workspaces\projname-eclipse-ws\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\4.0.1\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-api-6.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
maj 22, 2013 5:10:34 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\ProjName\Workspaces\projname-eclipse-ws\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\4.0.1\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-3.2-b05.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
maj 22, 2013 5:10:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I've checked my web.xml and I don't have any entries related to *ConfigureListener*.

I have both javaee-api-6.0.jar and javax.servlet-3.2-b05.jar set to *provided*. The workaround is that I'm deleting both jars from *C:\ProjName\Workspaces\projname-eclipse-ws.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\4.0.1\WEB-INF\lib* after deploying application via Eclipse.

My question is why is Eclipse deploying these jars to Tomcat regardless setting their scope to *provided*? Is there any other place that controls jars deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have jar in your lib - faces-sources-1.2.0.09.jar ?

if not then add it to your project. you can download it from here - http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomspringsourcecomsunfacessources12009jar.htm